# How to put EDIT and DELETE buttons at the end columns for data grid view retrieved directly from database?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, datagrid

I've this datagrid view in which filled directly from binding with database.

I get the data from database in controller in `OleDbAdapter` type and retrieve it in main window place it in the data grid view. After that, I add the buttons for `EDIT` and `DELETE` using `DataGridTemplateColumn` in `Main Window.xaml`.

**PROGRAM_CONTROLLER.CS**

```
public OleDbDataAdapter GetProgramList()
{
        OleDbDataAdapter da = null;

        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Path + ";Persist Security Info=True";
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from program";
            return new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return da;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
}
```

**MAIN WINDOW.CS**

```
Program_Controller _PController = new Program_Controller();
OleDbDataAdapter da = _PController.GetProgramList();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridProgram.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

**MAIN WINDOW.XAML**

```
<WrapPanel Margin="20,0,20,20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGridProgram" SelectionMode="Single" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="1" IsReadOnly="true" Height="300" Width="700">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Height="Auto" Width="75" Margin="10" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" Height="Auto" Width="75" Margin="10" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
</WrapPanel>
```

Currently the output result shows the `EDIT` and `DELETE` buttons are at the first and second column is like this.

[image: Current table for data grid view]

How can I move them to the back end of row and how to put them both in only one column?

**EDIT :** I
I only want the buttons column at the back, other should remained follow the sequence of columns in database

Comment: <DataGrid FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ...

Comment: @UsmanAli I've edited the question. Using FlowDirection will reversed all columns. But I specifically want the buttons column to be at the end but others remained in sequence, following the database column...

Comment: is AutoGenerateColumns="True"  necessary?

Comment: Since I don't define any column header and directly took everything from database, I think yes it is necessary. When I turn it into `false`, nothing come out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid
        Name="dataGridProgram"
        AlternatingRowBackground="#FFA3A3A3"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Background="#FF969696"
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="40"
        DataContext="{Binding}"
        FontSize="15"
        Foreground="Black"
        GridLinesVisibility="All"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        RowBackground="#FFCECDCD">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="60"
                Binding="{Binding ProgramI}"
                Header="ID"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Visibility="Visible" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="60"
                Binding="{Binding ProgramType}"
                Header="Type"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Visibility="Visible" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="60"
                Binding="{Binding ProgramPath}"
                Header="Path"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Visibility="Visible" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="btnEdit"
                            Width="75"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Margin="10"
                            Click="btnEdit_Click"
                            Content="Edit" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="btnDelete"
                            Width="75"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Margin="10"
                            Click="btnDelete_Click"
                            Content="Delete" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for come out with this. But I tried this also, yes the buttons move to the end row but the data inside the all cells does not come out.

Comment: Binding="{Binding ProgramI}"  instead of ProgramI put your coulmn name

Comment: do you mean exactly same with the database column name?

Comment: oh now it works. thanks. I will accept this answer now. but somehow I notice that it took longer time to load the data grid using the code compare to the previous one. do you maybe know why?

Comment: in <DataTemplate> create stackpanel or grid and put both buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188691/discussion-between-usman-ali-and-hna).

Comment: @UsmanAli This doesn't work anymore or is there a type of using for DataGridTextColumn?